# Creating a pandas dataframe using a dataset with hindi, or indic languages

Tags: python, nlp

I have the following  [dataset] [1](https://www.kaggle.com/disisbig/hindi-text-short-summarization-corpus), I wish to create a dataframe out of it using Pandas(python). How to do it?

I am getting the following error

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
```

in ()
2 import pandas as pd
3
----> 4 df = pd.read_csv(r"/content/drive/MyDrive/DRDO project documents/datasets/article_summary_heading/test.csv",encoding="latin-1")

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
2155     def read(self, nrows=None):
2156         try:
-> 2157             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
2158         except StopIteration:
2159             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.

Answer (score -1):

You can read the dataset using `pd.read_csv()`.

```
pd.read_csv('/path/to/csv')
```